# Megiddo's algorithm for lines of least weighted sum distance from a set of points

Tags: geometry, algorithms, optimization, euclidean-geometry

I came across the following problem:

Given a set of n points (coordinate in 2d plane) within a rectangular space, find out a line ($ax+by=c$), from which the sum of the perpendicular distances of all the points will be minimal.

I found a [paper](http://theory.stanford.edu/~megiddo/pdf/leastdis.pdf) by Nimrod Megiddo with a solution.

The author first proves that such a line will pass through any two of the $n$ points. Then he proposes an $O(n^2 \log(n))$ algorithm which I am not able to understand. Could anyone help me understand the algorithm explained on page 208–209 of this paper.